# Convert c# windows panel to c HWND

Tags: c#, hwnd

I have a dll which accepts HWND, 
(code in the dll);

```
void VideoCapture::SetVideoWindow(HWND VidWind)
{
    VideoWindow = VidWind;
}
```

i am calling the above dll in a sample c#.net application by adding the dll in references, in c#.net i have a form with Panel, is it possible to pass that panel to the dll?
i gave code as below in c#

```
VidCapWrapper.ManagedVideoCapture cc = new VidCapWrapper.ManagedVideoCapture();

cc.SetVideoWindow( panel1);
```

i am getting errors as below:
'Error  2   The best overloaded method match for 'VidCapWrapper.ManagedVideoCapture.SetVideoWindow(HWND__*)' has some invalid arguments D:\DirectShow_Capture_GUI\DirectShow_Capture_GUI\Form1.cs   44  13  DirectShow_Capture_GUI
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' to 'HWND__*'   D:\DirectShow_Capture_GUI\DirectShow_Capture_GUI\Form1.cs   44  32  DirectShow_Capture_GUI`

Can any one please tell me how to pass panel to dll, (any example will be good)?
(sorry i am very new to .net, but trying to create a sample app which shows available devices like integrated webcam... and then shows preview on c#.net form panel)

**EDIT**:
Thanks to Both @Blachshma and @Hans Passant, Now i am able to pass c# windows form's panel to my c++ dll.

I changed my func in dll as

```
void VideoCapture::SetVideoWindow(IntPtr windowHandle)
{
    VideoWindow = (HWND)windowHandle.ToPointer();
}
```

and in c# i am calling it as 
cc.SetVideoWindow(panel1.Handle);

Comment: Is this a WinForms application?

Comment: Check to see if it has a Handle property (it will be an IntPtr most likely).

Comment: @ShivaKumar just a tip for this website (as I see this is one of your first questions), you need to put a @ sign in front of someone's name when you are posting a comment for it to show up that you mentioned them in their inbox. There are exceptions to this but it is the general case.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, OK i will do from now on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be careful to *not* expose fundamentally unmanaged types like HWND to C# code.  The C# compiler will not allow you to pass a value of such a type.  The proper interop type here is IntPtr, it can store a handle value.  So make your C++/CLI method look like this:

```
void VideoCapture::SetVideoWindow(IntPtr windowHandle)
{
    VideoWindow = (HWND)windowHandle.ToPointer();
}
```

You can now simply pass panel1.Handle to the method, also of type IntPtr.

Comment: Thank you @Hans Passant, i am able to pass c# form panel to c++ dll.

Answer (score 1):

The panel has a `Handle` property you can use:

```
Panel p = new Panel();
IntPtr handle = p.Handle;
```

This should be enough if you set the `SetVideoWindow` signature to allow `IntPtr` i.e.

```
void VideoCapture::SetVideoWindow(IntPtr VidWind)
```

If you MUST use a HWND, you'll need to use an **[unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** context, and cast it like this:

```
HWND hwnd=(HWND)this.Handle.ToPointer();
```

Here is an [link](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/system-windows-forms-control-handle-hwnd-t3829987.html) with more information

Comment: thank you for the reply @Blachshma, i am able to pass panel to c++dll.